# Unable to create Dialogflow bot in Nigerian Language

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am Unable to create a bot for my Nigerian client, basically, I have created my bot in the English language but **the issue is Dialogflow is not recognizing Nigerian names**.

I have tried to add around 50+ names in sys.person entity but still, there are many names which Dialogflow does not recognizes.

I can not use sys.any entity as it will create conflict with first name and last name etc (which also may lead error to occur), is there any other permanent solution as Dialogflow also recognizes other languagees names (i.e Pakistani/Indian names).

Answer (score 1):

The sys.person entities are designed to recognize common names for your selected languages. This makes recognizing uncommon names for a languages very difficult, this is a problem for every action that is trying to work with names. Here are some things you can try:

- Your best bet would be to create a bot in the language for which you
  are trying to recognize the names, so you can use sys.person. In your case this would be creating a Nigerian bot, but currently isn't [supported](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/language) by Dialogflow,
  so you would have to wait for this out of the box support.
- If you are working with a limited number of names, one option you could try expand the entity, but this will only be limited to the names in the entity, so this isn't great if you want to work with a lot of names.
- You could go for a sys.any approach by splitting up your question to first ask the user for their firstname and then for their lastname, but because you are using sys.any you might get some weird result, because it isn't trained to recognize names, it just takes in everything.
- Finally, would it be an option to recognize the user by something than their name, maybe an email for instance? You could use something like Oauth to do this for you, but this is a more advanced implementation.